# Send key down / up events for number keys using AppleScript

Tags: keyboard, applescript

I need to send a **key down / key up event** for number keys to an application using AppleScript. However, the commands:

```
key down "6"
delay 1
key up "6"
```

send the keystrokes as if they were coming from the number pad. I need them to be interpreted as coming from the number row at the top of the keyboard.

I’ve also tried using `(ASCII character 54)` instead of a literal, without success.

*Note I need key down to be sent – sending a `keystroke` or `key code` will not do.*

Answer (score 3):

Try sending `key down` the *virtual key code* instead of a keystroke literal, i.e.

```
key down (key code <int>)
```

where `int` is one of

```
1 → 18
2 → 19
3 → 20
4 → 21
5 → 23
6 → 22
7 → 26
8 → 28
9 → 25
0 → 29
```

You will find all virtual key codes declared in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h
```

but if you don’t feel like doing hex to integer conversion, the easiest way to look them up is probably to use [Key Codes](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/) by Many Tricks, [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10718489/edit) by [dj bazzie wazzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1075643/dj-bazzie-wazzie).

Comment: thanks... but that doesn't seem to work. the "key code" command sends the keystroke to the application, however the key up / down component is ignored.

Comment: @monofonik: Indeed - `key up/down` only works as expected with **modifier** keys.
While **NON-modifier keys** can be sent (using `(key code <n>)` syntax), the **up / down aspect is ignored**, making both `key down (key code <n>)` and `key up (key code <n>)` statements **effectively the same as `key code <n>`**.

Comment: Using `key down (key code <int>)`, with any `<int>` causas always `a` to be pressed. Any thoughts?

Comment: maybe this helps for the "a"-bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366014/script-auto-correcting-incorrectly-when-i-compile-and-key-down-key-up-not-workin/31909645#31909645

Answer (score 1):

Key down and up won't work when using system events you need key code or keystroke. Keystroke will perform it's value while key code needs the key number. Download the app 'Key Codes' from the app store to determine the correct key codes (it's free).

```
--activate the application (and it's first responder) first
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "1" --value "1"
    key code 18 --1 from upper num keys
    key code 83 --1 from num pad
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I actually need to press and hold keys, as opposed to just a keystroke.

Comment: Actually, `key down` and `key up` **will** work, though they are absent from System Event’s AppleScript dictionary (go figure – silent deprecation, maybe).